# Execute POST/GET request from an Email Template and handlle response

Tags: node.js, email, httprequest

there was an investigation task that was assigned to me by a collegue to check if it is possible to execute HTTP Requests and handle the response in the emails that we are sending. The emails are created using Mustache.js and we have buttons which call a GET request in the BE. To my understanding there is no way to execute JS in the email client as they do not allow it. Does anyone know if it is possible to send an http request and handle the response in the email client?